# Finding Intervals after Changing the Order of Integration

Tags: integration

**Problem:**

Let
$f(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2} \,dt.$ Find the average value of f on the interval $[0, 1]$.

**Thoughts:**

$\int_0^x e^{t^2} \,dt$ is a non-elementary integral. The average value of f, I believe, can be solved by $\frac{1}{A}\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ (where A is the area). The easier method would be to take the integral in respect to $x$ first, then taking in respect to $t$.
However, the issue I am currently experiencing is confusion of how to assign the intervals of the integrals when changing the order of integration.

My idea was $\int_0^1 \int_0^t e^{t^2} dx dt$, which yielded the result $\frac{e-1}{2}$. The area was equal to that restricted by $t=1, t=x, x = 0$, which is $\frac{1}{2}$. However, $e-1$ was not the correct answer.

Could someone explain the error in my methods and the intuition for finding the intervals after a change in the order of integral? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong here. First, the average value of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is, by definition, $\dfrac 1{1-0}\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. Second, when you change the order of integration (draw the picture!), you get
$$\int_0^1\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt\,dx = \int_0^1\int_t^1 e^{t^2}dx\,dt = \int_0^1 (1-t)e^{t^2}dt.$$

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the new intervals without a visual, or is that the most effective way in terms of intuition?

Comment: The picture is best. You can, with practice, deduce it algebraically. If we're looking at the triangle $\{0\le x\le 1, 0\le t\le x\}$, we can see that $0\le t\le x\le 1$, and so $0\le t\le 1$. And, similarly, for $t$ fixed, $t\le x\le 1$.